# SocketException(0x80004005) Tried to get access to a socket on a way which is not allowed by security

Tags: c#, security, sockets, exception

I am trying to join my friends server in Terraria, and when I try to join my friends server with Hamachi, it says:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException(0x80004005): Tried to get acces to a socket on a way which is not allowed by security. 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint.endPointSnapshot, SocketAddres, socketAddres)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint, remoteEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connecy(IPAdress adress, Int32 port)
at Terraria.Netplay.ClientLoop(Object threadContext)
```

Does anybody know what's causing it, and how to help it? Me and my friend both turned our firewalls off, and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your firewall truly is not on...
It seems like a Code Access Security problem to me.  That's a set of permissions set up in windows that can control what resources each application can access.  There's a commandline util for configuring it called "caspol.exe".  I'd suggest making sure your app has network I/O permissions (or All if you are lazy)